# How to dynamically add items to ListBox in Windows Phone 7/C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a ListBox defined in my app that I've populated with some static data in the XAML code. If I were to reference this ListBox in my C# code, e.g.

```
searchList.....;
```

What method does one use to then dynamically add items to that ListBox in your code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [listBox.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx).

Example:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Your item");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's the one! Thank you very much.